# foreach loop from array displays all values on page load

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have an associative array that contains key pairs for the titles of a jQuery navigation list that is working for the

portion of the code. See left side of the picture below:

[image]

The problem is on the right side. The list on the right is automatically populating, when it should be the content for the tab "Appalachian & Rural Studies". When I load the page, this is generated, but when I click any of the individual links, the code works correctly and only displays the content area heading associated to the correct tab, see below:

[image]

Here is the code doing all of this:

```
<!-- Tabbed research areas content -->
<h4>Research Areas</h4>
<hr></hr>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabs li").click(function() {
    //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
    $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');

    //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
    $(this).addClass("active");

    //  Hide all tab content
    $(".tab_content").hide();

    //  Here we get the href value of the selected tab
    var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    //  Show the selected tab content
    $(selected_tab).fadeIn();

    //  At the end, we add return false so that the click on the link is not executed
    return false;
});
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
<div id="tabs_wrapper">
            <div id="tabs_container">
            <?php 
                $Researchareas = array(
                     '1' => 'Appalachian & Rural Studies',
                     '2' => 'Child Welfare',
                     '3' => 'Gerontology',
                     '4' => 'Human Trafficking',
                     '5' => 'International Social Work',
                     '5' => 'Intimate Partner Violence',
                     '7' => 'LGBTQ',
                     '8' => 'Substance Abuse and Misuse',
                     '9' => 'Suicide Survivors and Bereavement',
                     '10' => 'Trauma and Post-Traumatic Stress',
                     '11' => 'Veterans and Military Social Work'
                );
                ?>
                <ul id="tabs">
                <?php 
                    foreach ($Researchareas as $key => $value){
                        $tabname = 'tab'.$key; 
                ?>
                    <li><a href="#<?php echo $tabname ?>"><?php echo $value ?></a></li> 
                <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs_content_container">
                <?php
                foreach ($Researchareas as $key => $value) {
                    $divtab = 'tab'.$key;
            ?>
        <div id="<?php _e($divtab); ?>" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
        <h4><?php _e($value); ?></h4>
            </div>  
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>

<!--end tabbed research content area-->
```

I essentially just need the  to not load all of the array values in a complete list on page load, and instead, just display the first tab accurately, like in the second image. I'm not sure where I'm missing something, but I most definitely am. Any help is greatly appreciated and I will be forever thankful.

Comment: I'm guessing your .tab_content isn't hidden on the load of the document? (**display: block,**)

Comment: Nope, it isn't. Should I add the css and try to trigger it with javascript?

Comment: If you set display:none; on creating, does it work then?

Comment: .tab_content was already set to (display: none;) in my stylesheet. So, something else must be breaking it.

Comment: Could you throw this in a fiddle? Makes it easier to help..

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/772nLuxs/

Thanks for all the help. Had to strip my PHP out for the fiddle. I think the foreach loop is the problem but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I think I know your problem.. You are putting display: block, hard coded.. Which is probably why he is showing them all.. And my guess is it overwrites the css display: none;

Comment: How should I go about fixing it? Remove display: block? or try to make it happen in the jquery?

Comment: You could remove the display:block, and on document ready just set the first on visible, something like: $(".tab_content").first().css('display', 'block');

Comment: Sweeet. Works! Thank you so much kind person.

Comment: Could you move your correct comment to an answer segment so I can check it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete `display:block` from your HTML since it is overwriting your CSS.
If you have done this, they will all be invisible, so you should just need to put the first one visible on document ready, something like:

```
$(".tab_content").first().css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should trigger that initial click. You just bind the click event, but someone has to do the first click for it to show some effect. So after the bind function just add:

```
$("#tabs li:first").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for replying. I'm going to try this right now.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. I'm thinking this is a PHP issue more so than my javascript.